# How do you put $\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{6}$ into rational exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

For my precalc class we had the problem $\sqrt 3\sqrt[3]6$ and we had to convert it to rational exponents. I thought it was easy, $3^\frac 12\times6^\frac 13$ but the answer was $2^\frac 13\times3^\frac 56$. Any explanation please?

Comment: $6^{1/3} \ = \ (2 \ \cdot 3)^{1/3} \ = \ 2^{1/3} \ \cdot \ 3^{1/3} \ $ , so $ \ 3^{1/2} \ $ times that is...?

Comment: But I think your answer is also correct, unless there were other specs in the question.

Comment: You will find as you move toward progressively more advanced mathematics that there is often more than one way to express the same number or function, sometimes there are _many_ equivalent ways.  When you see an answer given, check to see if your own answer could be equivalent: students sometimes think they've done a problem wrong _just because_ the book's or instructor's answer is different(-looking).

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is correct, but it could be simplified further: $$3^\frac{1}{2}\times6^\frac{1}{3}=3^\frac{1}{2}\times2^\frac{1}{3}\times3^\frac{1}{3}=2^\frac{1}{3}\times3^\frac{5}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

As answered before, many equivalent solutions can be found. So you should try to put yourself in your teacher's shoes: gear toward "uniqueness" and simplicy. The $2^{\frac{1}{3}}3^{\frac{5}{6}}$ is somehow simpler because the factors are primes, and are written in increasing order. So you gain in simplicy (in a teacher's point of view) by careful factoring. Your initial guess, though correct, is a mere translation of the root expression, and brings no "added value" to your reasoning.